# Cannot read property 'lists' of undefined - Entire Function Undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, mongodb

My error message is telling me that what I'm attempting to call is undefined, but have no idea how that could be possible, because in an earlier version, everything worked perfectly.

I've had the **University's Web Development Professor** attempt to help, as well as the **Senior Design T.A.**

This is for my team's capstone project that we're presenting tomorrow.

*Please*, if you have any idea why this might be happening, we'd love to figure this out.

**Here is where the error is pointing**:

Specifically line 71 (I'll add an arrow)

```
import "./Board.css";

import React, {Component} from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { DragDropContext, Droppable } from "react-beautiful-dnd";

import List from "./List";
import AddList from "./AddList";
//import Navbar from "./Navbar";

class Board extends Component {
  state = {
    addingList: false
  };

  toggleAddingList = () =>
      this.setState({addingList: !this.state.addingList});

  handleDragEnd = ({source, destination, type}) => {
    // dropped outside the allowed zones
    if (!destination) return;

    const {dispatch} = this.props;

    // Move list
    if (type === "COLUMN") {
      // Prevent update if nothing has changed
      if (source.index !== destination.index) {
        dispatch({
          type: "MOVE_LIST",
          payload: {
            oldListIndex: source.index,
            newListIndex: destination.index
          }
        });
      }
      return;
    }

    // Move card
    if (
        source.index !== destination.index ||
        source.droppableId !== destination.droppableId
    ) {
      dispatch({
        type: "MOVE_CARD",
        payload: {
          sourceListId: source.droppableId,
          destListId: destination.droppableId,
          oldCardIndex: source.index,
          newCardIndex: destination.index
        }
      });
    }
  };


  render() {
    console.log(this.props)
    const {board} = this.props;
    //console.log(board);
    const {addingList} = this.state;

    try {
      return (
          <DragDropContext onDragEnd={this.handleDragEnd}>
            <Droppable droppableId="board" direction="horizontal" type="COLUMN">
              {(provided, _snapshot) => (


                  <div className="Board" ref={provided.innerRef}>     <---------------------------------------

                    {board.lists.map((listId, index) => {
                      return <List listId={listId} key={listId} index={index}/>;
                    })}

                    {provided.placeholder}

                    <div className="Add-List">
                      {addingList ? (
                          <AddList toggleAddingList={this.toggleAddingList}/>
                      ) : (
                          <div
                              onClick={this.toggleAddingList}
                              className="Add-List-Button"
                          >
                            <ion-icon name="add"/>
                            Add a list
                          </div>
                      )}
                    </div>
                  </div>
              )}
            </Droppable>
          </DragDropContext>
      );

    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error.onmessage);
    }
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ board: state.board });

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Board);
```

Thank you for any insight you might be able to send our way.

Comment: You attempt to access `lists` via `board`. Which you extract from `const {board} = this.props;`. That would mean that `board` is undefined. Unfortunately, that means it's likely an issue with `props` and therefore not present in the code you've provided, but in some parent component or wherever `board` is supposed to passed into `Board`.

Comment: @HenryEcker that's what others have said, but props is a node module, and therefore can't (shouldn't?) be altered.

Comment: My point is, however, that the error you are getting means `board` is somehow `undefined`. Since the only way this can occur, since you are extracting it from `props`, is if `board` is somehow becoming undefined in some parent component. Since you’ve not included the code where `board` is defined or where it is passed to `Board` it is not possible to make a reasonable guess as to the issue.